# When to use Azure Applicatio Gateway WAF vs. Azure Firewall?

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-web-apps

Can anyone here please share some thoughts and comments of when to use Azure WAF or Azure Firewall.
I have already existing Azure ExpressRoute so my Azure VMs can ping my OnPremise servers, and vice versa.

My purpose here is to be able to securely publish Azure Web Application & API that is accessing the database on my OnPremise SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application gateway provides a WAF for inbound connections only for HTTP/S traffic (OWASP rules and more), Azure Firewall provides both inbound and outbound filtering also for non-HTTP traffic (E.G. your VMs can only go out to FQDN X, Y on port Z, K. and block other traffic).

Comment: That's great, thank you @stefano.